# how to save and reuse values between two tikz pictures

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

I have two pictures in the first, I calculate the angle of a vector, I wish reuse this value in the second figure. How can I save this value from one figure to another.

The first picture

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (0,0){};
\node (J) at (3,2){};
\node(C) at (3,0){};
\newdimen\x
\newdimen\y
\pgfextractx{\x}{\pgfpointanchor{J}{center}}
\pgfextracty{\y}{\pgfpointanchor{J}{center}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\aaa}{atan2(\y,\x)}

\draw (C) --++(\aaa:3);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The other one

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) --++(\aaa:3);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

PS: do not hesitate to optimize my code to calculate the angle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, you can definitely save the value to use again.  AFter your call to `\pgfmathparse` you can do something like

```
\pgfmathparse{atan2(\y,\x)}
\xdef\aaa{\pgfmathresult}
```

Or as in your case

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (0,0){};
\node (J) at (3,2){};
\node(C) at (3,0){};
\newdimen\x
\newdimen\y
\pgfextractx{\x}{\pgfpointanchor{J}{center}}
\pgfextracty{\y}{\pgfpointanchor{J}{center}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\aaa}{atan2(\y,\x)}
\xdef\aaa{\aaa}

\draw (C) --++(\aaa:3);
\end{tikzpicture}

And then later

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) --++(\aaa:3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I.e. `\pgfmathparse{atan2(\y,\x)}
  \xdef\aaa{\pgfmathresult}` in the first picture.